# Apply play framework evolution in test Environment

Tags: testing, playframework-2.3, playframework-evolutions

I am set up my play framework jpa as following:

in application.conf:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password=""
applyEvolutions.default=true
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I am start play in test as this:

```
start(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase(), globalSettings));
```

running this project working well but testing it fails because of lacking database evolution!

How can I enable Play Framework evolution in test environment?

I am using hibernate 3.6

Comment: Same problem, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Force down evolutions too in your `application.conf` :

```
applyDownEvolutions.default=true
```

Be careful, if you use the same conf file in production.

Comment: My problem is Ups part! No evolution applied in test environment

Comment: Yes. I am retry it just now. but evolutions not applied

Comment: The documentation says : "Evolutions are automatically activated if a database is configured in application.conf and evolution scripts are present. You can disable them by setting evolutionplugin=disabled. For example when tests set up their own database you can disable evolutions for the test environment." https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Evolutions
Try disabling the evolution plugin for test maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to "none" and hence your evolutions should apply correctly.

I guess hibernate "assumes control" before the evolution plugin and that causes problem. You may try to modify plugin loading order (JPAPlugin vs EvolutionPlugin) to see if it makes any difference.